# Binding doesn't work - No property, bindable property, or event found error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Am having an issue with binding, but I first searched with several questions on this, but no luck, below is the error am getting :

> Error: Position 18:36. No property, bindable property, or event found
>   for 'Lat', or mismatching type between value and property

Below is my **xaml** file :

```
<controls:MapView x:Name="map" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <controls:MapView.Center>
                <controls:Position Lat="{Binding latitude}" Long="{Binding longitude}" />
            </controls:MapView.Center>
        </controls:MapView>
```

Then the **`c#`** code is as below :

```
public partial class DisplayMap : ContentPage
    {

        private double latitude { get; } 
        private double longitude { get; } 

        public DisplayMap()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.latitude = 0.3476;
            this.longitude = 32.5825;

            BindingContext = this;

        }
```

***What am I missing ?***

Comment: The binding there in your code example uses the BindingContext of the MapView. However, you are setting the BindingContext for the DisplayMap. Try setting the BindingContext of the MapView control instead...

Comment: which map control are you using?  are you sure Lat and Long are bindable properties?

Comment: am using a library called https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms/ @Jason. Let me check their library if it has bindable properties.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be a lack of publicly-accessible bindable properties in the `Position` class (notice that the error mentions `Lat` which is a member of `Position`). `Position` should look something like this:

```
public class Position : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LatProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Lat), typeof(double), typeof(Position), 0);
    public double Lat
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(LatProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(LatProperty, value); }
    } 

    public static readonly BindableProperty LongProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Long), typeof(double), typeof(Position), 0);
    public double Long
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(LongProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(LongProperty, value); }
    }

    // ...
```

I suggest you take a look at the [official documentation for Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties). Essentially, the error message you are getting is because it is looking for `LatProperty` when trying to bind using the accessor `Lat`.

Comment: So this means that I can't bind unless, I edit the mapView library to this code.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris If in the library they have not implemented `Lat` and `Long` as bindable properties then you can try to edit the `Position` class in the library itself or, in your project, you can just create a new class that inherits from `Position` and implement the bindable properties in that new class (if you can override `Lat` and `Long` then that might be easiest).

Comment: Actually I had started editting it but `this.GetValue` and `this.SetValue` are not existing in the current context. I also read on the documentation link you provided.

Comment: Make sure that your class inherits from `BindableObject`, that's where those methods are defined.

Comment: Thanks this removed the errors, now I need more of your advice, I tried to create another class to override the `Lat` and `Lon`, but the challenge comes in when I have to inherit `BindableObject`. It's like I have to embed the library code in project without using it's nuget package.

Comment: Looking in the source code for the library you linked, `Position` does not inherit from anything so you won't be able to make a new class that inherits from `Position` because then you can't inherit from `BindableObject`. If I were you, I would just copy the `Position` class from https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms/blob/master/Naxam.Mapbox.Forms/Position.cs, paste it into your project, make it inherit from `BindableObject`, and implement `Lat` and `Long` with bindable properties (as shown in my answer). Then, in your XAML just reference your new class in place of `controls:Position`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, let me do that.

Comment: So I have tried it but this but the error slight change to this  



`Error: Position 22:18. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Center', or mismatching type between value and property. (Via)`

Comment: This library is becoming too complex

Comment: That seems very strange to me. Perhaps create a new question for the new issue so that we can see your new XAML.

Comment: If there's a way of setting the `Lat` and `Long` without binding in XAML  but using c# code , this will be great.

Comment: If you want to avoid bindings, something like this should work... XAML: `<controls:MapView x:Name="map" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />`. Code Behind (in `DisplayMap` constructor): `this.map.Center = new Position { Lat = this.latitude, Long = this.longitude };`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it worked , maybe let me go with this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to use the Lat and Long property is that if you check the [Position](https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms/blob/master/Naxam.Mapbox.Forms/Position.cs) class there is no Bindable Property defined for them in it which means you cannot access them in XAML,

A possible solution is to download the Sample project and take the code and make the respective changes for it to have Bindable Properties.

For that, you can check @Aaron's answer